# when multiple threads access a class variable, is the variable common to all the threads?

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I have multiple threads accessing the same class variable.If one of the threads make a change to the class variable, will the change be reflected when the other threads access the variable?
Or is a copy of the class created for each of the threads? Because if this is the case then the change will not be reflected.

Comment: Do you mean class variable or instance variable? Are you setting it within `__init__`?

Answer (score 4):

All threads (`threading.Thread`) in python share the same global scope.

So you can do something like the following:

```py
from threading import Thread

class foobar:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


def foo(inst):
    print(inst.value)
    inst.value = 1337

inst = foobar(42)
thread = Thread(target=foo, args=[inst])
thread.start()
thread.join()
print(inst.value)
```

which will print `42` followed by `1337`

You need to be careful though, while reading and writing are atomic by default in python, e.g.:

```py
value = 12

print(value)
```

will work correctly, you will get problems when doing more complex stuff like:

```
value = value + 1
```

which is no longer thread safe, because it first reads the value and then writes it.
To make this work you would need to use a lock / mutex.

Please take a look at [Python Thread Synchronization](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) for a comprehensive guide about threads & locks in python.

Answer (score 1):

Class variables are updated on the class itself. This means that all instances of the class will see the change. If this is the desired behavior, using class variables is fine, however, if the variable should hold data specific to the instance, use an instance variable.

```
class MyClass:
    # This should not be used unless you understand how class variables
    # work.
    class_var = 'foo'

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = 'bar' # All threads can read and write to this.
```

Here's an example of when updating a class variable can have unintentional consequences.

```
class Foo:
    bar = 'baz'

a = Foo()          # First instance created.
a.bar              # 'baz'
Foo.bar = 'spam'   # Class variable update happens.
b = Foo()          # Second instance is created.
b.bar              # 'spam'
```

If the class variable is changed between instantiation of the same class, the overwritten name "carries over" to the new instance. This should be obvious since the second instance is created with the class after its attribute was updated.

But look at this:

```
print(a.bar)
print(b.bar)
```

prints:

```
spam
spam
```

We changed the `bar` attribute of the first instance as well. While it might be obvious that updating `Foo.bar` will affect `bar` on the second instance (since its defined before instantiation) it may not be obvious that it has also been changed on the instance created *before* the class attribute was updated.

In the case of multithreading - if the threads update a class variable, each thread's update will affect *all other instances* of the class. If this is not desirable, use instances variables instead.

Comment: What "issues"? If you're going to make a categorical statement like that, you should support it with examples and/or references. The language semantics of changing a class variable are just as well-defined as for changing an instance variable.

Comment: @GilHamilton Well, honestly none *if its done correctly*. However in practice, exposing `self.myvar` as well as `myclass.myvar` introduces the potential for the programmer to use (and confuse) both, causing...well....*issues*.

But you're right, the semantics are solid, however IMHO If it might change, its best to use an instance attribute.

Comment: I will update my answer with another odd case, not necessarily relevant to OP's question, but will highlight what I'm trying to get across.

Comment: @GilHamilton Take a look at my updated answer. I think the example highlights the "issues" I mentioned. Thanks for you comment - it definitely needed to be expanded.

Comment: I'm with @That1Guy, I've never introduced a class variable and though "gosh, that was a good use case". I always end up changing it an instance var. One good use case for class-level variables is for constants. Beyond that, I stay away from them.

Comment: Your example is correct, and yet, simply demonstrates the way class variables are *intended* to work. Which makes the argument tautological: don't ever change a class variable because it changes the class variable. So, I still disagree with your categorical statement that class variables should not be modified. I would argue rather that they should only be modified if you understand and intend the effect it has. Also this has nothing to do with multithreading. The "mis-use" of class variables affects objects in exactly the same way in a single threaded application as in a multi-threaded one.

Comment: @GilHamilton You're right that I shouldn't say "never". If you know what you're doing, its fine. In the case where OP has a single instance, using multiple threads will not make a difference, however, in the case where multiple instances are running, the threads from instance A can and will affect instance B, and so I maintain they shouldn't be used unless you completely understand the consequences. I will update the phrasing of my answer because I do agree that if you're aware of the affects, using them is fine.